# Clustered Index 'Seek predicate' and 'predicate' on the same column

Tags: sql-server, index

I have a clustered index primary key column and I'm doing a range query on it.
The problem is the scan only uses the first range part for the seek predicate, leaving the other side of the range as a residual predicate.
which causes to read all the rows up to the @upper limit

I'm using two parameters for the range:

```
declare
    @lower numeric(18,0) = 1000,
    @upper numeric(18,0) = 1005;

select * from messages
where msg_id between @lower+1 and @upper;
```

In that case the actual execution plan shows:

- predicate: messages.msg_id >= lower
- seek predicate: messages.msg_id < @upper
- rows read: **1005**

Table definition (Simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[messages](
    [msg_id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Message] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [msg_id] ASC
)
```

**More information**

When used with constants instead of variables both of the predicates are 'Seek'
Have tried `Option (Optimize for (@lower=1000))`, without success

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with your original query:

```
declare
    @lower numeric(18,0) = 1000,
    @upper numeric(18,0) = 1005;

select * from [messages]
where msg_id between @lower+1 and @upper;
```

The `1` that you added has a data type of `integer` by default. When adding an `integer` value to a `numeric(18,0)` value SQL Server applies the rules of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). `int` has a lower precedence so it gets converted to a `numeric(1,0)`. Your query is equivalent to the following:

```
declare
    @lower numeric(18,0) = 1000,
    @upper numeric(18,0) = 1005;

select * from [messages]
where msg_id between @lower+CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(1, 0)) and @upper;
```

A different set of rules around [Precision, scale, and Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is applied to determine the data type of the expression involving `@lower`. It isn't safe to just use `NUMERIC(18,0)` because that could be overflowed (consider 999,999,999,999,999,999 and 1 as an example). The rule that applies here is:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ Operation ║          Result precision           ║ Result scale * ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ e1 + e2   ║ max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1 ║ max(s1, s2)    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

For your expression, the resulting precision is:

```
max(0, 0) + max(18 - 0, 1 - 0) + 1 = 0 + 18 + 1 = 19
```

and the resulting scale is 0. You can verify this by running the following code in SQL Server:

```
declare
@lower numeric(18,0) = 1000,
@upper numeric(18,0) = 1005;

SELECT 
  SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@lower+1, 'BaseType') lower_exp_BaseType
, SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@lower+1, 'Precision') lower_exp_Precision
, SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@lower+1, 'Scale') lower_exp_Scale;
```

This means that your original query is equivalent to the following:

```
declare
    @lower numeric(19,0) = 1000 + 1,
    @upper numeric(18,0) = 1005;

select * from [messages]
where msg_id between @lower and @upper;
```

SQL Server can only use `@lower` to do a clustered index seek if the value can be implicitly converted to `NUMERIC(18, 0)`. It is not safe to convert a `NUMERIC(19,0)` value to `NUMERIC(18,0)`. As a result the value is applied as a predicate instead of as a seek predicate. One workaround is to do the following:

```
declare
    @lower numeric(18,0) = 1000,
    @upper numeric(18,0) = 1005;

select * from [messages]
where msg_id between TRY_CAST(@lower+1 AS NUMERIC(18,0)) and @upper;
```

That query can process both filters as seek predicates:

[image: seek predicates]

My advice is to change the data type in the table to `BIGINT` if possible. `BIGINT` requires one fewer byte than `NUMERIC(18,0)` and benefits from performance optimizations not available to `NUMERIC(18,0)` including better support for bitmap filters.

Answer (score 4):

There is an expression on one of your filters (`@lower+1`) which is making the engine do a regular predicate rather than a seek predicate (makes it non SARG-able).

Try changing the filter's value before the `SELECT` statement and you will see that both ends will be correctly used as the seek boundaries.

```
declare
    @lower numeric(18,0) = 1000 + 1,
    @upper numeric(18,0) = 1005;

select * from messages
where msg_id between @lower and @upper;
```

[image]